# How can I change background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I started to learn coding recently, and downloaded a template to work on it. I tried to add new sections to a page from different page. This section is from About us page and contains image and context, and I want to add it to destination section. I added one section successfully, but when I tried to multiple the sections I came across a problem. So, the image does not change it only stays which I refereed in the first section.
Below I will add screenshots of webpage and code.

```js
/* - About Section */
function about_img() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var about_content_height = $(".about-section").height();
  if (width >= 992) {
    $(".about-section .about-img img").remove();
    var about_image = $(".about-section .about-img").attr("data-image");
    $(".about-section .about-img").css({
      "background-image": "url('" + about_image + "')",
      "height": about_content_height
    });
  } else {
    $(".about-section .about-img").removeAttr("style");
    $(".about-section .about-img img").remove();
    var about_image = $(".about-section .about-img").attr("data-image");
    $(".about-section .about-img").append("<img src='" + about_image + "' />")
  }
}
```

```css
.about-img {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<!-- About Section -->
<div id="about-section" class="container-fluid no-left-padding no-right-padding about-section">
  <!-- About Image -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-am-12 no-padding about-img" data-image="images/destination-1.jpg">
    <img src="images/destination-1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <!-- About Image /- -->
  <!-- About Content -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 about-content">
    <!-- Section Header -->
    <div class="section-header">
      <h3>We Share Something</h3>
      <h6>With me</h6>
    </div>
    <!-- Section Header /- -->
    <div class="about-content-box">
      <h4>The mate was a mighty sailin man the Skipper brave and sure. Five passegers set sail.</h4>
      <p>The Love Boat soon will be making another run. The Love Boat promises something for everyone. who wabusy with three boys of his own. Sunny Days sweepin' the clouds away. On my way to where the air is sweet. Can you tell me how to get how to get
        to Sesame Street The mate a mighty sailin' man the Skipper brave and sure. Five passengers set sail that day for a three hour tour a three hour tour. Till the one day when the lady met this fellow more than a hunch.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- About Content /- -->
</div>
<!-- About Section /- -->
<!-- About Section -->
<div id="about-section" class="container-fluid no-left-padding no-right-padding about-section">
  <!-- About Content -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 about-content">
    <!-- Section Header -->
    <div class="section-header">
      <h3>We Share Something</h3>
      <h6>About us</h6>
    </div>
    <!-- Section Header /- -->
    <div class="about-content-box">
      <h4>The mate was a mighty sailin man the Skipper brave and sure. Five passegers set sail.</h4>
      <p>The Love Boat soon will be making another run. The Love Boat promises something for everyone. who wabusy with three boys of his own. Sunny Days sweepin' the clouds away. On my way to where the air is sweet. Can you tell me how to get how to get
        to Sesame Street The mate a mighty sailin' man the Skipper brave and sure. F
ive passengers set sail that day for a three hour tour a three hour tour. Till the one day when the lady met this fellow more than a hunch.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- About Content /- -->
  <!-- About Image -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-am-12 no-padding about-img" data-image="images/destination-2.jpg">
    <img src="images/destination-2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <!-- About Image /- -->
</div>
<!-- About Section /- -->
```

Comment: There are duplicate `id`s within HTML. An HTML `document` should contain elements with unique `id`s. You can substitute `class` for `id` at HTML and get the element by class name at JavaScript.

Comment: Yep, duplicate id within HTML, but that is not the issue (still, please change those). You will have to loop through the `.about-section` , because right now it takes the first DOM element and apply the image url to the others.

Comment: @Cryptomothy, thank you for your great solution. Could you please tell me how exactly to loop the .about-section when tried it messed up, and changed the design :/

Comment: @HeydarAliyev I added an answer with the loop, take a look, feel free to use it and upvote if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have duplicated IDs in your HTML and that's a big no no. So you'll want to change that. But that's not the issue!

Second, you'll need to loop through the `.about-section`. Because you have two of them, your code simply doesn't work.

(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbdMQg is that what you were looking for?)

Here is a snippet of what the loop looks like:

```
$('.about-section').each(function(){
    var about_content_height = $(this).height();
    if (width >= 992) {
        $(this).find(".about-img img").remove();
        var about_image = $(this).find(".about-img").attr("data-image");
        $(this).find(".about-img").css({
            "background-image": "url('" + about_image + "')",
            "height": about_content_height
        });
    } else {
        $(this).find(".about-img").removeAttr("style");
        $(this).find(".about-img img").remove();
        var about_image = $(this).find(".about-img").attr("data-image");
        $(this).find(".about-img").append("<img src='" + about_image + "' />")
    }
});
```